# How to forward port between localhost and two remote hosts

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

`localhost` can access `host-a` and `host-b`.
`host-a` cannot access `host-b`.
`host-b` can access `host-a`.

How can I connect to a service on `host-b` from `host-a`?

Comment: *host-b can access host-a* ... just connect from B to A?

Comment: @Jakuje that is correct. `host-b` only allows specific connections, one of which is my `localhost`, but not `host-a`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `autossh` with `-R` for an easy way out. (not very secure)
Correct way is to use `ssh -R` w/o `ssh -L` if you want security.

Or just use `socat tcp-listen:myport tcp-connect:b:b-port` and on `host-a` connect to the `intermediate-host:myport`

You can use `nc -l -p port` and `nc addr port` for testing

Comment: Can you check your last statement? The manual for `nc` option `-s` reads
"It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the `-l` option."